# Incorrect file path being used within submodule

Tags: java, spring, maven

A multi-module project which works for my colleagues fails for me. The problem arises during any test which references a file and in the spring configuration files when they reference a file. The reference never includes the sub module folder name, or full file paths don't get resolved correctly.

For example `ParentProject` is the parent and `ChildProject` is the sub module.

```
ParentProject
    - ChildProject
        - src/test/java/my/package/MyTest.java
        - src/test/resources
            - xml/myfile.xml
            - myProperties.properties
            - mySpringConfig.xml
```

If I have the following in `MyTest.java`:

```
File file = new File("src/test/resources/xml/myfile.xml");
String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

Then `absolutePath` is `C:\ParentProject\src\test\resources\xml\myfile.xml` which is incorrect as it's missing the `ChildProject` folder and so it throws a `FileNotFoundException`.

Getting the same issue with any mention of properties files in the spring configuration files e.g. in  `mySpringConfig.xml` I have the line:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:myProperties.properties" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>
```

However on trying to build the project I get:

```
IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\test\resources\myProperties.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

I get the feeling it's a classpath issue. I have maven 3.0.3 set up and working with installed java version (verified with `mvn -version`). And both java and javac versions are correct from command line.

Any ideas?

Added the full -X output for debugging:

```
[25/04/13 13:45:21:812 BST] [main] ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@a166bd] to prepare test instance [my.package.MyTest@60029d]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:308)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:220)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:301)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:303)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:35)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
        at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:150)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:91)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\test\resources\myProperties.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:78)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:663)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:638)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:407)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\test\resources\myProperties.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:70)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:161)
        at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:124)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:181)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:161)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:69)
        ... 39 more
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in your examples is correct; Maven normally changes into subdirectories as it builds the project, so the problem must be elsewhere.

When you look into `absolutePath`, you can see that this doesn't happen. It's as if "someone" is trying to execute the code for the module `ChildProject` from `ParentProject`.

To find out what happens, you can try to run Maven with `-X` to turn on debugging. Also make sure that `ChildProject` is correctly referenced in the parent POM using a `module` element.

Comment: The child project is correctly referenced in the parent pom, and its on the parent pom that I'm running `mvn clean install` (however I still get same result if I run directly in submodule). I'll add the -X output, however I did write the original high level error messages in my post.

Comment: The error *must* go away when you run `mvn clean install` inside of the child folder. If the error is still there, remove things from the POMs. Also try `mvn help:effective-pom` and search for paths in the output. When using `-X` always pipe the output to a file and then examine that with a text editor or `grep`.

Comment: It wasn't maven. It was my own stupid fault. I'd added a shortcut to make the command prompt default to a folder. Unfortunately some of the tests being run would call ant scripts which would reopen new instances of the command prompt with the incorrect path. Hence the failures. My own silly fault. So much for timesaving shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason that you are reading file like that?

I believe the file is bundled in the project jar.

In that case you can read it as a classpath resource - `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xml/myfile.xml")`